# Nmap does not show all devices connected to my network

Tags: nmap

I want to use xerosploit but when I scan my network, it just shows two devices

1. My device
2. My Router

Then I thought there was some problem in xerosploit, but when I scanned my network through `nmap` it also shows the same result. Why?

The command I used on `nmap` is `nmap -sn ip addr/24`. I even tried the Aggressive Scan option, but it still only showed these two hosts up.

Answer (score 0):

Two things come to mind, and both of these could contribute to your problem:

1. If you inserted your machine's entire IP address and added the `/24`, this is not a valid netmask for your use case. If you wanted to scan 192.168.1.1 through 192.168.1.254, the proper IP for `nmap` is `192.168.1.0/24`. For a /24, take the first three octets of your computer's IP and set the last digit to zero. If you are on a more complicated network, [use a subnet calculator](https://www.subnet-calculator.com/) to determine what your scan range should be.
2. You may have devices on your network not responding to pings, which in the default mode of `nmap`, will cause them to report as down without any actual port scanning. To have it try anyways, use the option `-Pn`.

Comment: I was using my ip as you said in 1. point and even used -Pn command still it is showing me just two devices my pc and my router. I was even trying to scan my network using xerosploit but even there i found only two devices. Also i want add i am connected to my network using ethernet is it fine or wireless connection is neede?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. At the end of the troobleshooting, I had an vmware worksation with an overlapped network configured in my computer :/ . You should easily find an overlapping network issue with an ipconfig /all (windows) or ip a (linux). Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your virtual box network is nat.
if it is then change it to Bridge adapter.
It'll run properly.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YE5Za.png)